# How to set the number of decimals in set sthg random-float 1?

Tags: netlogo

how can I set the number of decimals to 2 when I use `set size random-float 1`? 
Right now I have `0.12433242` but I would like `0.12` (approximated). 
I know that there is `show precision 2`, but I do not know how to include it in that command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Val, if you use "precision" in a display command,  like show or print, it only affects the displayed value and doesn't touch the actual value.   If you use "precision" in a set or let command,  it will change the actual stored value,  rounding it off to that many decimal places.

Here's code you can try:

```
to setup

  let x random-float 1
  type "original value has high precision: "  
  print x

  type "shown as low precision but value still high precision: " 
  print precision x 3

  type "confirm we didn't affect the original value: " 
  print x

  ;; actually change the value to 3 decimal places using "precision" in a set command
  set x precision x 3

  ;; confirm that worked
  type "New value actually has fewer decimals: " 
  print x

end
```